# CSS: How to place a <script> element on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a web application using AngularJS.
I have a problem: in an HTML page I needed to show a table that dynamically show the number of rows based on a user's choice. I achieved this effect using a **script** and **bootstrap** rules.
I won't go into details, but I just show you the high-level code and a screenshot of the result:

**HTML code:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom/pager">
    <ul class="pager ng-cloak">
        <!-- Code of the element drop down menu.....-->
    </ul>
</script>

<div>
    <ng-form >
        <div class="panel panel-default table-panel noborder">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table ng-table-dynamic="$ctrl.tableParams with $ctrl.cols" class="table" template-pagination="custom/pager">
                     <!-- Code of the table.......-->
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

The result is something like that:
[image]

My problem is that **no type of CSS code seems to work** to move the dropdown menu position to this position:

[image]

I tried to use `position` (`relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`) and also to encapsulate the `<script>` element inside `<div>` or `<span>` and refer it with CSS rules. But nothing seems to work! The dropdown menu always remains at the bottom and center of the page. I guess it's bootstrap's fault. Can you tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you at least include the CSS code?

Comment: And also, you can't put html code in the script section.

Comment: @Chris without details or more information, that isn't a helpful comment

Comment: @coder9927 that's an angular inline template script element, not a javascript script element

Comment: Ok sorry, It now make sense.

Answer (score -1):

The pagination buttons are working. If the css should also work. You can place the below code into the codepen to see the effect.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/jPxgzY)

```
.table{
  position:relative;
 
}
 .ng-table-counts{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
  }
```

Comment: Why there is a negative rating? What is expected?

Comment: The question is about moving the "show X rows" to the top right of the table. It's still at the bottom in your codepen.

Comment: Please read out. I said to put the css code in that codepen. That code pen was not written by me. Please read out before pointing some is wrong.

Comment: @Alaksandar Jesus Gene, Thanks for the effort but your answer is not good for the presented problem.